# How to Generate Downloadable QR Code in Java using zxing?

Tags: java, zxing

I have a code in java to generate a QR code using zxing. currently my code is able to  save the image for a given path. but I need to download it via browser. How can I do it? please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Use zxing to generate data representing the image.
Save the image on your server.
Add a webpage with HTML to show the image.
Use Apache to show the webpage on a hosted URL.
Use a browser to hit the hosted URL.

Image should appear in the browser